# Is it possible to link more than 7 HP blade enclosures (c7000)?

Tags: hp, blade-server, bladecenter

I have 4 enclosures c7000 per rack. All enclosures inside a rack are interlinked. I log into the first enclosure of a rack and can oversee all interlinked too. Is it possible to interlink more than 7 enclosures? Like 20 or 40?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Virtual Connect Multi-Enclosure Stacking Reference Guide](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02102153):

> Up  to  4  Virtual Connect-enabled  C7000  enclosures  can  be stacked  together  and  managed  as  one  Virtual  Connect  domain for  128 servers, not to exceed a total of 16 VC-Enet and 16 VC-FC modules (a Virtual Connect FlexFabric module counts as both one VC-Enet  module  and  one  VC-FC  module  towards  these  limits).